# How to cluster (or group) the data from a CSV file?

Tags: python, list, csv, cluster-computing

I have a three column data set in CSV,

```
A,B,10
A,C,15
A,D,21
B,A,10
B,C,20
```

I want to group or cluster A,B,C,D pairs based on the third column. The condition is the increment of 10. 0-10 one cluster, 11-20 another cluster and so on. Each cluster will contain pairs of A,B,C,D. Basically if the third column is in between 0 - 10 a pair will go to first cluster. A,B has 10 in third column so they go in the first cluster. I expect it to be 10-15 clusters.

Here is how I opened CSV:

```
fileread = open('/data/dataset.csv', 'rU')
readcsv = csv.reader(fileread, delimiter=',')

L = list(readcsv)
```

I have created a set:

```
set(item[2] for item in L if (item[0]=='A' and item[1] == 'B' and item[2] <= 10)
```

My basic question here is that how to check the third column and store the pairs in a cluster?

Comment: What have you tried so far? The syntax in your example at the end suggests a dictionary - have you tried that? Can you generate the `output-produced-by-thrid-column-comparison` [sic]? What exactly is your question?

Comment: @jonrsharpe just a thought: instead of quick to judge and downgrade people's questions, just think for a bit and act... as tobias_k did... Then it will be a better community

Comment: Just a thought: read the material in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and use it to ask better questions. This question still lacks a working [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code so far and a clear description of the problem - consider including an example input along with expected and actual output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this: Loop the data and determine the groups by integer-dividing the third element by 10.

```
import csv
with open('data.txt') as f:
    groups = {}
    for item in list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')):
        n = int(item[2]) // 10
        group = "%d-%d" % (n*10, n*10+9)
        groups.setdefault(group, []).append(item[:2])
```

Using your data, `groups` ends up as this:

```
{'20-29': [['A', 'D'], ['B', 'C']], 
 '10-19': [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['B', 'A']]}
```

Dictionaries are unordered, so if you want to print them in sorted order you have to sort the keys. This is a bit tricky, since they are strings and would be sorted lexicographically. But you could do this:

```
for k in sorted(groups, key=lambda k: int(k.split('-')[0])):
    print k, groups[k]
```

(or use just the smaller number as key in the first place)

Comment: worked well... but it skipped some there is 151-160 in the CSV but it started from 120-129 and jumped to 50-59...

Comment: I think dict is not in order.

Comment: That's normal. Dictionaries are always unordered. If you want to print them in sorted order, just sort the keys... but as it is now, the keys are strings, so '150-159' would be ordered before, e.g. '20-29'. Of course, you could use just 150 and 20 as keys, then this will work.